# Help finding a philosophy webpage that used Socratic dialogues

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a page that had debates structured around a Socratic dialogue where one side was illustrated as an angel and the other as a machine or robot. It was quite minimalist in design. Hope you can help.

Comment: Imagine you believe you've arrived at such a page, what rigorous (academic) criterion will you use to identify which is angel and which is robot? Turing test? Or other philosophical terminology in mind?